# Need details or clarity

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I need some help to understand what is unclear with my question [A reform of logic to secure naive set theory?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/364615/a-reform-of-logic-to-secure-naive-set-theory) and also what details are missing, from other persons perspective.